# .NET Core & Entity Framework - complex query

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with a database query from .NET Core, through Entity Framework; I think it can't be done.

I put you in situation: I have a table of employees and another of actions, with all the actions performed by the user.

Would it be possible, in a single query, to retrieve the entire list of employees, along with the actions they have performed "in the last 30 days"?

When I get the query, I make a query to all the employees that are enabled and I include them in the list of actions, but if I filter in it because the date is less than 30 days and there is no record, the employee does not appear, and I need it to appear with the empty list.

I need **all employees** with all actions in a period or anything actions if not have it.

Comment: `if I filter in it because the date is less than 30 days and there is no record, the employee does not appear` Just use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN and it'll appear no matter what.

Comment: Possible - this is the answer to the question that you have asked. If you need more details, post your model classes and result class.